# Create (k, v1, ..., vn) tuples based on matching dict keys

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.6, and I have two datasets, each being a list of dictionaries. The two datasets look like this:

```
[{'foo': 3}, {'bar': 4}]
[{'bar': 1}, {'foo': 8}]
```

From these two datasets, I want to create a single list of tuples that would look like this for the input data:

```
[('foo', 3, 8), ('bar', 4, 1)]
```

It is important that the number in the first dataset come first in the resulting tuple, btw.

I've actually accomplished this through various means (including a nested list comprehension), but it seems like it should be simpler/cleaner. I was surprised that nothing in itertools jumped out at me (though I did do one implementation w/ chain that resulted in a 2-tuple where the ints were in a list). Can anyone provide a clean solution, or is there just not one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

datasets = [{'foo': 3}, {'bar': 4}], [{'bar': 1}, {'foo': 8}]    

result = defaultdict(list)

for dataset in datasets:
    for eachdict in dataset:
        for key, value in eachdict.iteritems():
            result[key].append(value)

# the nested loops as a one-liner (utterly unnecessary):
# any(result[key].append(value) for dataset in datasets 
#                               for eachdict in dataset 
#                               for key, value in eachdict.iteritems())


# if you really need your output in exactly that format:
# result = [(key,) + tuple(values) for key, values in result.iteritems()]
print result
```

That seems like the cleanest approach to me.

Comment: This is almost precisely what I had settled on doing already, but thought I'd reach out for other input. Thanks for validating my thinking :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an [inner join operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) and we have a tool that does that:

```
>>> ds1 = [{'foo': 3}, {'bar': 4}]
>>> ds2 = [{'bar': 1}, {'foo': 8}]

>>> import sqlite3
>>> c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c.execute('CREATE TABLE ds1 (key text PRIMARY KEY, value text)')
>>> c.execute('CREATE TABLE ds2 (key text PRIMARY KEY, value text)')
>>> c.executemany('INSERT INTO ds1 VALUES (?, ?)', [d.items()[0] for d in ds1])
>>> c.executemany('INSERT INTO ds2 VALUES (?, ?)', [d.items()[0] for d in ds2])
>>> c.commit()
>>> r = c.execute('SELECT ds1.key, ds1.value, ds2.value FROM ds1 INNER JOIN ds2 ON ds1.key=ds2.key')
>>> list(r)
[(u'foo', u'3', u'8'), (u'bar', u'4', u'1')]
```

The [sqlite3 module](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) comes with Python and doesn't require you to create and maintain an actual database in order to perform SQL queries on your data sets. So if you don't get your data from a database and can't alter a query to bring it back in a form that best suits your application, you can still massage the data using SQL, which can be very convenient.

Using an SQL approach has several advantages 1) the code expresses its intention clearly (I am joining two datasets on a common key), 2) it makes it easier to consider correctness issues (such as keys present in one dataset but not the other, 3) it is easy to extend to multiple fields or switch to a multi-field key, 4) ordering may be specified.

Comment: The original question has nothing to do with sqlite or databases in general.

Comment: @jonesy So? That doesn't mean you can't use a database to solve it. The output is still the data you wanted. Admittedly, unless there is a significant performance advantage, I prefer actually doing it in Python.

Comment: The original question also didn't have anything to do with defaultdicts.  In fact, what you're doing is an inner join operation.  The tool you use to solve it notwithstanding. The point of the post is people frequently use dictionaries to reinvent common database operations when they could be using a tool that is already optimized for it.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger - I misinterpreted the answer as assuming I was getting my data from a db and therefore should just change the query to get the data back in a more suitable form. I've edited the answer to try to negate my -1, to no avail. I think *you* have to edit it. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks guys.  This post may be a reflection of our toolset biases.  It's a bit ironic that using a DB tool for a fundamental database operation is considered clever while reinventing it using dictionaries is considered to be the plain, straight-forward approach. ;-)